# How to delete columns based on certain condition?

Tags: r, data.table

I want to delete columns based on certain conditions.

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(1:4, rep(TRUE, 4), c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE))
```

In this case I want to delete columns that are all `TRUE`. Output should be

```
 # V1    V3
 #  1  TRUE
 #  2 FALSE
 #  3  TRUE
 #  4  TRUE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can exclude them from selection using subsetting

```
dt[,!sapply(dt, function(x) all(x==TRUE)), with=FALSE]
```

Here the `sapply(dt, function(x) all(x==TRUE))` part finds the columns where all values are TRUE. Then we negate it and use `with=FALSE` (since this is a data.table and not a data.frame)

On current devel version of `data.table` (2020-04-24), we can do this in `.SDcols`:

```
dt[ , .SD, .SDcols = function(x) !is.logical(x) || !all(x)]
```

Answer (score 3):

`Filter()` is a useful function for selecting columns of a data-frame according to whether a particular function evaluates to TRUE. In your case:

```
Filter(function(x) !all(x == TRUE), dt)

   V1    V3
1:  1  TRUE
2:  2 FALSE
3:  3  TRUE
4:  4  TRUE
```